# When finding the median in a table, how do I specify to ignore NaN values?

Tags: numpy, nan, median

I am trying to find the median of a table without it considering the NaN values in the table.  Is there a simple way to have the function ignore those values?

INPUT

```
data_source = (r"C:\Users\mburen\Desktop\TestPython2.xlsx")
bk = pd.read_excel(data_source)
print("Here is what the original excel table looks like. The bk table.")
print (bk)
print ()

#now for finding the median
x=np.median(bk)
print (x)
```

OUTPUT

[image: Here is the table]

The median is the calculated central number of all the values. The median is:
nan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you see np.nanmedian introduced in numpy 1.9?
[nanmedian](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmedian.html)

Comment: Thanks for all the edit work @Markus!  And yes that worked. I can now use it along the separate axes to analyze my data.